# I get bolt unexpected error when I launch neo4j console in command line

Tags: neo4j

I am new to neo4j. When I ran the neo4j console and after I enter the credentials, I am able to get to the browser interface. But, whenever I refresh the browser, the command line window shows an error like below:

> ERROR Unexpected error detected in bolt session
>   '00000000000000e0-000023c4-00000006-99adaeeaf773dc11-cde05595'. Failed
>   to process a bolt message
>   org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltConnectionFatality: Failed to process a
>   bolt message
>           at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.handleFailure(BoltStateMachine.java:742)
>           at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.handleFailure(BoltStateMachine.java:728)
>           at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.access$500(BoltStateMachine.java:62)
>           at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine$State$1.init(BoltStateMachine.java:435)
>           at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.init(BoltStateMachine.java:145)
>           at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.messaging.BoltMessageRouter.lambda$onInit$0(BoltMessageRouter.java:70)
>           at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.DefaultBoltConnection.processNextBatch(DefaultBoltConnection.java:195)
>           at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.DefaultBoltConnection.processNextBatch(DefaultBoltConnection.java:143)
>           at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.ExecutorBoltScheduler.executeBatch(ExecutorBoltScheduler.java:170)
>           at org.neo4j.bolt.runtime.ExecutorBoltScheduler.lambda$scheduleBatchOrHandleError$2(ExecutorBoltScheduler.java:153)
>           at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.neo4j.bolt.security.auth.AuthenticationException: The client is
>   unauthorized due to authentication failure.
>           at org.neo4j.bolt.security.auth.BasicAuthentication.doAuthenticate(BasicAuthentication.java:78)
>           at org.neo4j.bolt.security.auth.BasicAuthentication.authenticate(BasicAuthentication.java:60)
>           at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachineSPI.authenticate(BoltStateMachineSPI.java:93)
>           at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine$State$1.init(BoltStateMachine.java:412)
>           ... 10 more

Is it fine to get such error. I am able to access my graph without issues but I am curious if it creates any connection related issue when I launched it on one of our servers. Please guide me.

Comment: I even added dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687 to neo4j/conf file also uncommented dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:7687.

Comment: I figured it out. Instead of running it as a console. I have installed the service and started it. I am not getting any bolt error message even when the browser refreshes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/11972 and https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12067 this "error" should apparently be treated as a warning.

From what I understand, it can occur:

- when you don't supply the correct credentials for `:server connect`
  on the browser UI
- or when the browser tries a command to test if auth is enabled or not on the database...